# Как получить ссылку страницы для парсинга?

Tags: python, парсер, ссылки, веб-сайт

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как я могу обратиться к нужной странице, чтобы взять с нее данные для парсинга, если напрямую не получается это сделать.
Вот страница с выбором списков: [Списки поступающих](https://abiturientu.kai.ru/spiski-postupausih?p_auth=oR89u3Ml&p_p_id=listentrant_WAR_listentrant10&p_p_lifecycle=1&p_p_state=normal&p_p_mode=view&p_p_col_id=column-1&p_p_col_count=1&_listentrant_WAR_listentrant10_pageName=listEntrant&_listentrant_WAR_listentrant10_javax.portlet.action=getList)

нужный список:

Подразделение - институт компьютерных технологий и защиты

Уровень образования - Программа бакалавриата

Направление - 01.03.02 Прикладная математика и информатика

Форма обучения - очная

Вид приема - общий конкурс

Вот именно ссылка этой страницы мне нужна. Подскажите, как ее можно получить.

Comment: селенимум не пробывали?

Comment: пробую. Но можете подсказать как использовать его для выбора элементов из выпадающих списков?